# How to edit .bst file `format.vol.num.pages output`?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

I am familiar a bit with the following `bst` code and if I move up or move down one line its appearance in pdf will change accordingly.

```
FUNCTION {article}
    { output.bibitem
        format.authors "author" output.check
        new.block
        format.title "title" output.check
        new.block
        crossref missing$
        {
            journal
            "journal" bibinfo.check
            emphasize
            "journal" output.check
            add.blank
            format.date "year" output.check
            format.vol.num.pages output
        }
        { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
            format.pages output
        }
        if$
        new.block
        format.url output
        new.block
        format.note output
        format.eprint output
        fin.entry
    }
```

But I don't know how to take apart elements of `format.vol.num.pages output` and use them separately?

I tried `format.vol output` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `format.vol.num.pages` is a function defined elsewhere in the `.bst` file. A function called `format.vol` may or may not exist. Depending on what you want to do, you might need to redefine `format.vol.num.pages` or to define a new function that does what you want.

Comment: Aha, I find it. `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}` how to modify this one?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want vol-(year)-pages

Comment: Can you post the complete `.bst` file (it's probably too long to be included here directly, use a text-sharing website like https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, ... instead)?

Comment: I am modifying the `nature.bst`. you can find it in internet or in your texlive folder. You can also modify `plain.bst` as well.

Answer (score 3):

`format.vol.num.pages` is a function defined elsewhere in the `.bst` file. A function called `format.vol` does not exist.

For the desired "`<volume>` () " order you may want to define

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.year.pages}
{ "{ \bfseries " volume field.or.null * "}" * % make volume bold face
  year empty$
    'skip$
    { " (" year * ")" * * }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
%        { ":" * pages n.dashify * } % TDS
        { ", " * pages n.dashify * } % comma, not colon TDS
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

instead and use that as follows

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF
      format.vol.year.pages output  % these now do their own comma!!
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: `format.chapter.pages is an unknown function---line 2417 of file mybib.bst
format.chapter.pages is an unknown function---line 2431 of file mybib.bst
format.chapter.pages is an unknown function---line 2481 of file mybib.bst
format.chapter.pages is an unknown function---line 2493 of file mybib.bst
Database file #1: refers.bib`

Comment: `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Mardia"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Kato_Jones"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Yfantis"
0 is an integer literal, not a function, for entry vv
while executing---line 2989 of file mybib.bst
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry vv
while executing---line 2989 of file mybib.bst
1 is an integer literal, not a function, for entry vv
while executing---line 2989 of file mybib.bst
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry vv`

Comment: @C.F.G Well, my code does not say anything about `format.chapter.pages` at all. In my version of `nature.bst` the function is defined in l. 431. But your BibTeX complains about it. The warnings about entries that cannot be found can have multiple reasons (are you sure they are in your `.bib` file). The errors about `vv` can only be investigated with the entry at hand and with the complete `.bst` file.